# .equals with other Boolean functions

Tags: java, string, boolean

In a small segment of my program I'm trying to validate if someone enter M,m,F,f and for the most part I got it, but something seems wrong when I put the statements together. For example,

```
   String _gender = "M";
   if(!"m".equals(_gender.toLowerCase())||!"f".equals(_gender.toLowerCase())){
      System.out.println("try again");
   }else 
      System.out.println("success");
```

It tells me to try again, but when I put it as:

```
  String _gender = "M";
   if(!"m".equals(_gender.toLowerCase())){
      System.out.println("try again");
   }else 
      System.out.println("success");
```

It gives me a success. I don't know if its something with how I'm using the or, but thats what I've guessed. I also think it may be something to do with the fact that the check is checking both or something. Idk I've been at this for a while and its been confusing me.

Comment: Corollary to Thunderbolt's reply below: Look up DeMorgan's Theorem.  What you're trying to say is "if not A or B".  That's `if( !(A||B) )`.  To remove the parenthesis, you need to do `if( !A && !B )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Let's evaluate your code:

```
String _gender = "M";
if(!"m".equals(_gender.toLowerCase())||!"f".equals(_gender.toLowerCase()))
```

`if(!true || !false)` => `if(false || true)` => `true`

Now you understand the reason why you got the output, `try again`.

### Now, let's fix it:

Do it as

```
String _gender = "M";
if (!("m".equals(_gender.toLowerCase()) || "f".equals(_gender.toLowerCase())))
```

which evaluates to
if `(!(true || "f".equals(_gender.toLowerCase())))` => `(!(true))` => `false`

which will give you the intended output, `success`

Answer (score 4):

There is logical mistake. It should go into "try again" when both equal() results are false.

```
String _gender = "M";
if(!"m".equals(_gender.toLowerCase()) && !"f".equals(_gender.toLowerCase())){
  System.out.println("try again");
}else 
  System.out.println("success");
```